# VPN on demand Connection in iOS7 not connected but shown as active

Tags: ios7, vpn, ondemand

I have a Problem with **iOS7** and **VPN on demand**.

If I call a Webservice VPN on demand starts the connection. 
The VPN Symbol is shown in the Statusbar and everything works fine.

Now I wait for a minute or two for sending another request. *The VPN Symbol is still shown in the statusbar*, but the connection is not valid. 
*The request will run into empty and the services isn't called*.

So my question, is there any posibility to cancel the vpn connection or to keep it alive? What do i need to build a per App VPN?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could give it a try on per app vpn also.Can you tell me what VPN client you are using in iOS.is it OpenVPN or Juniper

Answer (score 1):

I am also using On-Demand VPN in iOS 7 and I am not experiencing this issue

### Suggestion 1:

It seems like buggy beta os version update to latest one and try that's enough.

### Suggestion 2:

If the VPN server is down it may happen so make sure VPN sure in online and available.

### Suggestion 3:

Review your mobile config xml for any bug below is part of my mobile config I use.

```
<key>OnDemandEnabled</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>OnDemandMatchDomainsAlways</key>
                <array>
                    <string>*</string>
                    <string>google.com</string>
                </array>
                <key>OnDemandMatchDomainsNever</key>
                <array/>
                <key>OnDemandMatchDomainsOnRetry</key>
                <array/>
                <key>OnDemandRules</key>
                <array>
                    <dict>
                        <key>Action</key>
                        <string>Connect</string>
                    </dict>
                </array>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So it looks like the Routing doesn't work fine. Some tests show us that the vpn works perfectly with wifi. In the mobile network, the vpn gateway can't reach the iPhone for a heartbeat.

Comment: @Gulliva - it seems some problem with mobile config ...can you share yours so that I can verify it.